# Angular5, setting active class for RouterLink

Tags: angular

I am trying to distinguish currently selected routerLink from others by giving it class which will change some styles.

So in html i added some properties and event to links.

app.component.html:

```
<nav class="nav-list">
  <a routerLink="/dashboard" 
     class="nav-link" 
     [class.activePage]="pageSelected === 'dashboard'" 
     (click)="setActivePage('dashborad')" >
     Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/products" 
     class="nav-link" 
     [class.activePage]="pageSelected === 'products'" 
     (click)="setActivePage('products')" >
  Products List</a>
</nav>
```

and in typescript I have implemented variable and method.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({   selector: 'app-root',   templateUrl: './app.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] }) 
  export class AppComponent {

  pageSelected:string;

  setActivepage(page){
    this.pageSelected = page;   }

}
```

but there is nothing happening after link click although activePage class is already set in styles.

Somebody got an idea how to make it work ?

Comment: see this https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#routerlinkactive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@vikas and @Mertcan Diken already showed you the solution! I show you how you should use it.

The 'angular' router knows which route is active and will set a class on the active `a` tag for you. You only have to define which class should be set.

.css

```
.active-route {
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;      
}
```

.html

```
<nav class="nav-list">
    <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active-route" class="nav-link" >Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/products" routerLinkActive="active-route" class="nav-link">Products List</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

You just need to use routerLinkActive prop for that on your routerLink's.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="nav-list">
  <a routerLink="/dashboard" 
     class="nav-link" 
     routerLinkActive="activeClass"
     (click)="setActivePage('dashborad')" >
     Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/products" 
     class="nav-link" 
     routerLinkActive="activeClass"
     (click)="setActivePage('products')" >
  Products List</a>
</nav
```

Comment: you do not know how to use ´routerLinkActive´. Delete your answer.