# How do I get the active route to highlight on my navbar?

Tags: html, css, angular

In angular I'm trying to make sure the page I'm on is highlighted on the navbar - I thought this might have been native to the bootstrap nav I'm using but it doesn't seem to be working.

**nav**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']"><fa-icon [icon]="faGlobeAmericas"></fa-icon>  Offshore</a>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']" style="color:white"><fa-icon [icon]="faHome"></fa-icon>  Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/results']" style="color:white"><fa-icon [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>  Search</a>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/links']" style="color:white"><fa-icon [icon]="faLink"></fa-icon>  Links</a>
  </nav>
```

Is there a css script or something I can use to achieve this?

Comment: use `routerLinkActive` attribute, see https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Angular, how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular5, setting active class for RouterLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300026/angular5-setting-active-class-for-routerlink)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive), it adds a CSS class to the element when the route is active.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']"><fa-icon [icon]="faGlobeAmericas"></fa-icon>  Offshore</a>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><fa-icon [icon]="faHome"></fa-icon>  Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/results']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><fa-icon [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>  Search</a>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/links']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><fa-icon [icon]="faLink"></fa-icon>  Links</a>
</nav>
```

I suggest removing the inline css for color you added and let Bootstrap handle the colors with classes. `active` should work for the `nav-link`, but feel free to experiment. They are added as an array, so you can add more than 1.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) attribute that'll add the class `active` to the link when active. This `active` class can have the styling you want to applied when the particular link is active.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/']"><fa-icon [icon]="faGlobeAmericas"></fa-icon>  Offshore</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/']" style="color:white"><fa-icon [icon]="faHome"></fa-icon>  Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/results']" style="color:white"><fa-icon [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>  Search</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/links']" style="color:white"><fa-icon [icon]="faLink"></fa-icon>  Links</a>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with `RouterLinkActive` like so:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="class1 class2">Bob</a>
<a routerLink="/user/bob" [routerLinkActive]="['class1', 'class2']">Bob</a>
```

More on this [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)